# Firestore trying to use orderBy to recieve a maximum field from a set of documents but it isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

```
const ref = collection(db, "users")
const q = query(ref, orderBy("score"));
```

So db is just my database, I get a reference to a collection called users and try to make a query to orderBy score but it returns some weird object.
[image]
And I can't really seem to find any data in there.
This is my firestore:
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

I tried looking up the documentation and it seems that I am doing everything right?

Comment: Let me know if you have some clarifications about my answer. Also, See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A&text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you're logging your query which is your variable `q`. You should execute the query to get the documents. See sample code below:

```
import { collection, query, orderBy, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const ref = collection(db, "users");
const q = query(ref, orderBy("score"));

// Executes the query above
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

For more information, you may refer in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).